# swift objective-c error Cannot convert value of type () -> () to specified type MIDI.IO.Manager

Tags: swift, objective-c

I am getting error: Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to specified type 'MIDI.IO.Manager'

I am going to be exposing the value create by the midiManager to React Native. Just don't understand Why I get the error with this code block

I am not sure how to fix this as I am new to swift and objective-c. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import Foundation
import MIDIKit

@objc(MidiManager)
class MidiManager: NSObject{
  
  var midiManager: MIDI.IO.Manager = {
          let newManager = MIDI.IO.Manager(
              clientName: "MIDIEventLogger",
              model: "LoggerApp",
              manufacturer: "Orchetect") { notification, manager in
                  print("Core MIDI notification:", notification)
              }
          do {
              logger.debug("Starting MIDI manager")
              try newManager.start()
          } catch {
              logger.default(error)
          }
    }
  

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted computable property, then

```
var midiManager: MIDI.IO.Manager {   // 1) remove =
      let newManager = MIDI.IO.Manager(
          clientName: "MIDIEventLogger",
          model: "LoggerApp",
          manufacturer: "Orchetect") { notification, manager in
              print("Core MIDI notification:", notification)
          }
      do {
          logger.debug("Starting MIDI manager")
          try newManager.start()
      } catch {
          logger.default(error)
      }
      return newManager   // 2) return object
 }
```

if you wanted initialised with default value then

```
var midiManager: MIDI.IO.Manager = {
      let newManager = MIDI.IO.Manager(
          clientName: "MIDIEventLogger",
          model: "LoggerApp",
          manufacturer: "Orchetect") { notification, manager in
              print("Core MIDI notification:", notification)
          }
      do {
          logger.debug("Starting MIDI manager")
          try newManager.start()
      } catch {
          logger.default(error)
      }
      return newManager   // 1) return object
 }()    // 2) make call
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a closure of type `() -> Void` to a variable of a type `MIDI.IO.Manager`. You need to change a closure a bit and then actually call it:

```
var midiManager: MIDI.IO.Manager = {
      let newManager = MIDI.IO.Manager(
          clientName: "MIDIEventLogger",
          model: "LoggerApp",
          manufacturer: "Orchetect") { notification, manager in
              print("Core MIDI notification:", notification)
          }
      do {
          logger.debug("Starting MIDI manager")
          try newManager.start()
      } catch {
          logger.default(error)
      }
      return newManager
}()
```

But personally I don't think that starting a manager already after an initializing is a good idea. If it fails with an error and you return it, application logic may break in some place.

Also you may want to make `MIDI.IO.Manager` `let` variable, i.e. immutable one.